# Confused about finding LCM of three numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the LCM of three numbers:

1. $x^2-36$
2. $2x^2-12x$
3. $x^2-6x$

I factor:

1. $x^2-36=(x+6)(x-6)$
2. $2x^2-12x=2x(x-6)$
3. $x^2-6x=x(x-6)$

Then I multiply all factors. Every factor that appears in all three expressions I multiply only once. $(2x)(x)(x-6)(x+6)$. And I get $2x^2(x+6)(x-6)$. But the solution is $2x(x+6)(x-6)$. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x$ is already contained in $2x$ thus $2\cdot x\cdot (x+6)\cdot (x-6)$ is the correct answer.

Indeed the different factors which appear are

- $2$
- $x$
- $(x-6)$
- $(x+6)$

Comment: But why do we not count $x$ when $2x=x+x$ and $x$ aren't same?

Comment: @Vuk Let consider $2x$ as the product $2\cdot x$, then x|2x of course.

Comment: In other terms, what is the LCM between 2x and x?